# Click on polyline also causes map click

Tags: here-api

When I add click listener for a polyline object, click on it also causes the map click, which I want to avoid, since map click triggers the expensive network operation. How should I subscribe to polyline clicks to avoid map clicks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call stopPropagation() on the event to prevent it from being passed to the polyline hierarchy. See https://developer.here.com/javascript-apis/documentation/v3/maps/topics_api_nlp/h-mapevents-event.html